# Android oppening other application activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have the followind code to open other app activity :

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activitate, MapFragment_.class);
                    shortcutIntent.putExtra("instantly", true);
                    shortcutIntent.putExtra("data", address);
                    shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);

And in my Manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MapFragment_.class"
    android:authorities="com.mobi.android.xyz"
    >

</activity>
```

And i recive :

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: Read this first: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not used startActivity(). Add this

```
  Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activitate, MapFragment_.class);
  shortcutIntent.putExtra("instantly", true);
  shortcutIntent.putExtra("data", address);
  shortcutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(shortcutIntent);
```

Comment: i have red characters on "MapFragment_.class" ( first line above ) : "Can not resolve symbol MapFragment_.class"

Comment: my current class  shortcut